# Having Jquery Loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I am having trouble getting this piece of code to loop. I want it to check what state the ID of  #94785 is and tell me.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#94785').each(function() {
        if ($('#94785').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') {
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            console.log('notchecked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the element with the id 94785 dynamically created? (That is, created AFTER the page loads)

Comment: Is everything working after my answer?

Comment: To answer your question is works with a slide show so that has to load first.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$('#94785')`

> ...the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

[More info](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#94785').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') {
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            console.log('notchecked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So this runs once and I need it to check if aria-hidden everytime.

Comment: Here is where I am using it. https://seanpisano.github.io/final-project/test-slide.html

Comment: What do you mean every time?

Comment: There is bottom slider that aria-hidden = false when you click or it comes in to the center view on the top slider that corresponds to the content. when the div has the aria-hidden = false  I want something to happen.

Comment: Is what I am saying making any sense?